# Submit button sends me to the top of the page

Tags: php, html, forms, form-submit

Firstly I'd like to say sorry about my bad english .

I want to say that before of creating this topic, I already checked other topics on here and tried solutions offered there but for me didn't work.

So, I have on my page at the bottom, a form which verify either the domain inserted in the form field is available or not.

So the HTML code is this:

```
<div class="row footer-newsletter justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <form action="#rezultat" method="GET" id="rezultat">
          <input type="text" name="domain" style="border: 0;padding: 4px 8px;width: calc(100% - 100px);" placeholder="Exemplu: numedorit.ro sau numedorit.eu" required><input type="submit" value="Verifica">
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
```

The action of the form doesn't have any .php file because the php code is in the same file with the above HTML and the code is:

```
<?php
          error_reporting(0);
          if(isset($_GET['domain'])){
            $domain = $_GET['domain'];
            if ( gethostbyname($domain) != $domain ) {
                echo '<center><strong><font color="red">Denumirea selectata nu este disponibila..</font></strong></center>';
            }
            else {
                echo '<center><strong><font color="green">Denumirea selectata este disponibila..</font></strong></center>';
            }
          }
        ?>
```

My problem occurs when I press the submit button because it sends me to the top of the page instead of sending me to the "#rezultat" anchor how do I plan.

I used that anchor because this is how I read on a topic here but it just doesn't work.
What I do notice is that after I press the submit button and it sends me to the top of the page, on the address bar I see:

```
http://********.ro/?domain=domain1234asd.com#rezultat
```

Where domain1234asd.com is the domain name I just checked if it is available or not.
The true is that my php code returns correctly either the domain is available or not and it returns me the correct html code with the result.

Thank you in advance for your replies.

**EDIT:**
@brombeer just gave me a good answer, the ' action="#rezultat" ' doesn't sends me to the anchor #rezultat because that anchor is the last element on the page, very down.
(IDK WHY ????? His comment is not there anymore, even if it was the only one correct ???????? omg..)

As a test purpose, I just set a new anchor somewhere in the middle of the page and it works good.
So the new question is how can I set the ' action="#rezultat" ' to send me to the ID 'rezultat' if this element is the last one on my page ??......

Comment: I don't understand the idea.
Why to add lots of lrem ipsum below my content ? I don't need those lorem ipsum....

Comment: @brombeer you are completly right !
I just set the action to another anchor which is somewhere on the middle of the page, and after i press submit php script runs -> returns the result -> send me to the new anchor at the middle of the page.
But the point is to send me to the bottom of the page where is my desired anchor.
How can i do that since this form i talk about is almost the las element on my page ?

Comment: Either move your form further up or add whitespace or  footer below it so it can scroll to the top of the page

Comment: I was able to create a new <a> tag under the form and form action pointing to that anchor and that worked perfectly.

Thank you very much @brombeer you're a genius.

Answer (score -1):

Hash character in URL use for navigate item which has id value equal to hash it is called URI Fragmentation. In your case rezultat when browser sees #rezultat in the url it tries to find the element with id="rezultat" if there is no element with that id browser send you top of the page. So instead of using #rezultat use it http://********.ro/domain=domain1234asd.com&hash=rezultat like this

Comment: Thank you for your reply!
I already post my html code so if you read on the 
<form action="#rezultat" method="GET" id="rezultat"> "
There is already an id which contains "rezultat" who stands as an anchor so the submit button should send me to the that ID.
Excuse me but your answer didn't help me that much or maybe I didn't understood very well what you wrote there.


By the way, i even tried to insert your url example: "http://********.ro/domain=domain1234asd.com&hash=rezultat" in the address bar and it still doesn't send me to that anchor.

Comment: What is `&hash=rezultat` supposed to do?

Comment: I don't know.... that sounds weird to me too...

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at this line,

```
     <form action="#rezultat" method="GET" id="rezultat">
```

You are sending your data to a page reference. This is why you cannot submit the data. You have to point this action to the link which enters your php get data .

**What is happening here?**

- When you are clicking submit it is getting you to the portion of the page where id is written/specified.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
The fact is that data is submited correctly, so after pressing submit button PHP code runs correctly and after checking if domain is available or not, it returns an html code with the result as specified at echo lines.
On the other hand, it is not happening as you said because if the submit button would get me to the portion of the page where id is written/specified, the problem would not exist. 
The ID is written/specified at the end of the page in the <form> tag.
<form action="#rezultat (i want it to send me to the ID )" method="GET" id="rezultat (ID is here)">

Comment: "_This is why you cannot submit the data_" OP _can_ submit data. And there does _not_ have to be a link in the `action` attribute. If it is empty the form will submit to the current page

Comment: @brombeer If it is empty php script is still working and returns me the right result but it still takes me to the top of the page and if add "#rezultat" in the action, it doesn't take me to the ID="rezultat"